# Get distinct values within specific attributes

Tags: xml, xpath, distinct

I've got the following XML Code:

```
<!-- language: xml -->
<Stats>
  <Stat>
    <Data Name="Value">63.76</Data>
    <Data Name="Entity">first</Data>
  </Stat>
  <Stat>
    <Data Name="Value">51.23</Data>
    <Data Name="Entity">second</Data>
  </Stat>
  <Stat>
    <Data Name="Value">46.1</Data>
    <Data Name="Entity">third</Data>
  </Stat>
  <Stat>
    <Data Name="Value">61.21</Data>
    <Data Name="Entity">first</Data>
  </Stat>
</Stats>
```

I want to filter only where 'Data[@Name='Entity']. Using xpath: `/Stats/Stat/Data[@Name="Entity"]` returns:
first
second
third
first

But I want the results to be unique. So I only get:
first
second
third

EDIT: I need this to work for xpath version 1.0.

Comment: duplicate->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016929/selecting-unique-records-in-xslt-xpath

Comment: I've seen this post, however - I do not think this one is duplicate. XML Code there:
    <Stats>
      <Stat>
        <Value>63.76</Property>
        <Entity>first</Property>
      </Stat>
    </Stats>

My XML Code:
    <Stats>
      <Stat>
        <Data Name="Value">63.76</Property>
        <Data Name="Entity">first</Property>
      </Stat>
    </Stats>

Comment: Bouke Groenescheij: Was my answer useful or do you still have any problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use this XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
/Stats/Stat
   [Data/@Name='Entity'
  and
   not(Data[@Name='Entity']  = following-sibling::Stat/Data[@Name = 'Entity'])
   ]
    /Data[@Name='Entity']
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
      "/Stats/Stat
           [Data/@Name='Entity'
          and
           not(Data[@Name='Entity']  = following-sibling::Stat/Data[@Name = 'Entity'])
           ]
            /Data[@Name='Entity']
      "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (produced by correcting the non-well-formed provided text):

```
<Stats>
  <Stat>
    <Data Name="Value">63.76</Data>
    <Data Name="Entity">first</Data>
  </Stat>
  <Stat>
    <Data Name="Value">51.23</Data>
    <Data Name="Entity">second</Data>
  </Stat>
  <Stat>
    <Data Name="Value">46.1</Data>
    <Data Name="Entity">third</Data>
  </Stat>
  <Stat>
    <Data Name="Value">61.21</Data>
    <Data Name="Entity">first</Data>
  </Stat>
</Stats>
```

**the above XPath expression is evaluated and the selected nodes are copied to the output:**

```
<Data Name="Entity">second</Data>
<Data Name="Entity">third</Data>
<Data Name="Entity">first</Data>
```

**Note**: If you just need the text nodes ("first", "second" and "third"), just use this single XPath expression:

```
/Stats/Stat
   [Data/@Name='Entity'
  and
   not(Data[@Name='Entity']  = following-sibling::Stat/Data[@Name = 'Entity'])
   ]
    /Data[@Name='Entity']
      /text()
```

Comment: Just awesome! Thank you very much for the fast and accurate reply. I've been looking for this for a long time. Especially the last Note did it - and the XSLT is a great bonus!

Comment: @BoukeGroenescheij: You are welcome. Yes, both XPath and XSLT are fascinating, powerful and elegant languages.

Answer (score 3):

You need to say which version of XPath. In XPath 2.0, it's trivial:

```
distinct-values(/Stats/Stat/Data/@Name)
```

Comment: Thank you. You're correct - sorry, I need this for XPath 1.0.

Comment: By the way, the above code doesn't give the desired results, since it returns Value and Entity. After changing it to: distinct-values(/Stats/Stat/Data[@Name='Entity]) it works - now I need to transform this into XPath version 1.0...