# Selecting only distinct values using XPath 1.0

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

How would I return only the ***unique*** `City` value where the `Name` of the `state = 'Washington'` using XPath 1.0?

```
<StateDataSet>
    <State>
        <Name>Washington</Name>
        <City>Seattle</City>
        <business>Starbucks</business>
    </State>
    <State>
        <Name>Washington</Name>
        <City>Seattle</City>
        <business>Amazon</business>
    </State>
    <State>
        <Name>Washington</Name>
        <City>Redmond</City>
        <business>Microsoft</business>
    </State>
    <State>
        <Name>Washington</Name>
        <City>Redmond</City>
        <business>Starbucks</business>
    </State>
    <State>
        <Name>Washington</Name>
        <City>Seattle</City>
        <business>Dicks</business>
    </State>
    <State>
        <Name>Alaska</Name>
        <City>Anchorage</City>
        <business>Starbucks</business>
    </State>
    <State>
        <Name>Oregon</Name>
        <City>Portland</City>
        <business>Starbucks</business>
    </State>
    <State>
        <Name>Alaska</Name>
        <City>Gnome</City>
        <business>Starbucks</business>
    </State>
</StateDataSet>
```

So far I've tried the following XPath query:

```
/StateDataSet/State[Name ='Washington' and not (State[Name='Washington'] = following-sibling::State[Name='Washington'])]/City
```

This returned the city in Washington but the values are not unique.  I tested my query using [xpathtester.com](http://www.xpathtester.com)

What am I doing wrong?  I'm basing my query on [get-distinct-values-within-specific-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532657/get-distinct-values-within-specific-attributes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath,

```
/StateDataSet/State[Name ='Washington' and 
                    not(City = preceding-sibling::State[Name='Washington']/City)]
             /City
```

will select the unique `City` elements in `State` elements with `Name = 'Washington'`:

```
<City>Seattle</City>
<City>Redmond</City>
```

as requested.