# Return Distinct Records of XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I am completely new to XML and XLST.  I have a report that spits out in XML.  It has several thousand records but it's the same two rows of data being repeated over and over.  I need a way to limit the output XML file to only those two unique rows of data.

Here is an example of what my XML file currently looks like:

```
<zd:Report_Data xmlns:zd="urn:com.xxxx.report/xxxx-Employee_Status-Outbound">
   <zd:Report_Entry>
<zd:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</zd:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<zd:empStat.name>Active Employee</zd:empStat.name>
<zd:worker>
<zd:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</zd:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<zd:empStat.actvInd>1</zd:empStat.actvInd>
</zd:worker>
   </zd:Report_Entry>
   <zd:Report_Entry>
<zd:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</zd:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<zd:empStat.name>Active Employee</zd:empStat.name>
<zd:worker>
<zd:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</zd:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<zd:empStat.actvInd>1</zd:empStat.actvInd>
</zd:worker>
   </zd:Report_Entry>
   <zd:Report_Entry>
<zd:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</zd:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<zd:empStat.name>Active Employee</zd:empStat.name>
<zd:worker>
<zd:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</zd:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<zd:empStat.actvInd>0</zd:empStat.actvInd>
</zd:worker>
   </zd:Report_Entry>
   <zd:Report_Entry>
<zd:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</zd:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<zd:empStat.name>Active Employee</zd:empStat.name>
<zd:worker>
<zd:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</zd:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<zd:empStat.actvInd>0</zd:empStat.actvInd>
</zd:worker>
   </zd:Report_Entry>
   </zd:Report_Data>
```

This is what I would like it to look like:

```
<zd:Report_Data xmlns:zd="urn:com.xxxx.report/xxxx-Employee_Status-Outbound">
   <zd:Report_Entry>
<zd:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</zd:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<zd:empStat.name>Active Employee</zd:empStat.name>
<zd:worker>
<zd:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</zd:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<zd:empStat.actvInd>1</zd:empStat.actvInd>
</zd:worker>
   </zd:Report_Entry>
   <zd:Report_Entry>
<zd:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</zd:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<zd:empStat.name>Active Employee</zd:empStat.name>
<zd:worker>
<zd:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</zd:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<zd:empStat.actvInd>0</zd:empStat.actvInd>
</zd:worker>
   </zd:Report_Entry>
   </zd:Report_Data>
```

^^updated

---

I saw something that I thought would work on this site (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016929/selecting-unique-records-in-xslt-xpath) but am having trouble applying it to my situation.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is what I have so far based on another post I read here.  Unfortunately it's not returning any data:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="kItemBy3Children" match="Report_Entry"
     use="concat(empStat.emplStatusCode, '+', empStat.name, '+', empStat.lastUpdateDate, '+', empStat.actvInd)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:copy-of select=
        "*/item[generate-id()
              = generate-id(key('kItemBy4Children',
                                concat(empStat.emplStatusCode,
                                       '+', empStat.name,
                       '+', empStat.lastUpdateDate,     
                                       '+', empStat.actvInd)
                               )
                            )
               ]
        "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: How far have you come? Do you have any (not yet completely correct) code to show? What exactly are you having trouble with? The more exact your description of the problem, the better we can explain it to you :-)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.  I added to my original post to show you what I've tried so far.

Comment: @micheal Kay..unfortunately that's not my problem.  The issue is there are thousands of records but it's the same two throughout and they aren't necessarily in order.  The first data set could show up 100x before the second appears.

Comment: @ O.R. Mapper...thanks.  Let me play with this for a bit.  I tried to dump into an xslt and it did't fail.  However, it didn't filter out the duplicates either.  It returned all the data from the report instead of the 2 unique records I am looking for.  I'm sure it's my error.  I am completely new to this so it's hard to troubleshoot my own issues.  Thanks again for your help and patience.

Comment: I have updated my answer so it contains a test case where duplicates are removed. I *suppose* you might be experiencing a namespace mismatch, so only the identity template was executed when you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This style-sheet ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:ZD="urn:com.xxxx.report/xxxx-Employee_Status-Outbound">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="kItemBy4Children" match="ZD:Report_Entry"
     use="concat(ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode, '+', ZD:empStat.name, '+', ZD:worker/ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate, '+', ZD:worker/ZD:empStat.actvInd)"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ZD:Report_Data">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    <xsl:copy-of select=
      "ZD:Report_Entry[ generate-id() = generate-id(key('kItemBy4Children',
       concat(ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode, '+', ZD:empStat.name, '+', ZD:worker/ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate, '+', ZD:worker/ZD:empStat.actvInd))[1])]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... will transform this input document ...

```
<ZD:Report_Data xmlns:ZD="urn:com.xxxx.report/xxxx-Employee_Status-Outbound">

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>1</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Terminated Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>0</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>1</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Terminated Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>0</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

</ZD:Report_Data>
```

... into this output document ...

```
<ZD:Report_Data xmlns:ZD="urn:com.xxxx.report/xxxx-Employee_Status-Outbound">
  <ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>1</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>
  <ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Terminated Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>0</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>
</ZD:Report_Data>
```

---

## Explanation

The Report_Data nodes are grouped into groups with the same content as measured by the 4 child members. In other words there is exactly one group per distinct Report_Data, and only the first member of each group is output. The technique is called Muenchian grouping. I could give a long explanation of Muenchian grouping or you could just search for the several hundred StackOverflow questions which already explain this. I would only be repeating what some-one else has written.

Starting points for search:

- Stackoverflow (search on Muenchian)
- Google
- http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

## UPDATE

I made a correction the empStat.emplStatusCode field and the empStat.name field should be prefaced by ZD:worker/

Comment: In my opinion, this answer lacks an explanation. For anyone who doesn't yet know how this works, this isn't very helpful; in particular not for other visitors who are having similar problems and aren't looking for a ready-made solution for exactly this task. Maybe you can update it; I'd be interested in learning more about this way to solve the task :-)

Comment: Thanks so much for checking this out!  Man, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  I am getting the full file back (20k+ records) instead of just the two that I need.  I updated my original post to include everything from my xml output in case there is something there that was missing.  I did notice that your solution doesn't include the "worker node" as two of the fields in each record are beneath it.  Could that be part of it?

Comment: Thanks. Good catch. That was an error on my part. I have updated and corrected accordingly. Try it now.

Comment: I am still getting the full set of records.  I tried dumping it into xml playground and the duplicates didn't filter out.

Comment: This style-sheet works for me. Are you testing my style-sheet as-is? or adapting it? Can you link me to what you tried on xml playground?

Comment: I was running it 'as-is.'  Here is my link.  Thanks again!

http://www.xmlplayground.com/P0pv7a

Comment: Oh, I get it! Its name-spaces. I think in your original post, you did not declare the ZD name-space, so I made up one as you can see in my style-sheet. My made-up ZD is not the same as your ZD. See updated answer.

Comment: Sean B. Durkin!!!!!  Thanks a million.  It worked like a charm and ran in like 25 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to select the first two rows, that's very easy:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="*[1]|*[2]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But perhaps I have misunderstood the problem.

Comment: Yes you have. The OP wants the list of distinct records. It just so happens in his sample data, there are 2 distinct records, but in general, there could be any number. He's got the right general idea about solving the problem with grouping. He just made a few errors in applying grouping to his problem.

Comment: Well, perhaps it was pedantic to answer the question as stated: "it's the same two rows of data being repeated over and over. I need a way to limit the output XML file to only those two unique rows of data." rather than attempting to solve a more general problem. Who knows?

Answer (score 0):

This is a different solution than your attempt, because I am not using any keys. I think it is easier like this, because you do not have to know how keys in XSLT work (in fact, I don't know how they work because I never needed them so far).

Note that I've declared some URI for your namespace prefix `ZD`; you'll need to insert yours.

First, I have applied the identity template to basically copy all the contents.

Then, there's a template for `<ZD:Report_Entry>` elements. In that template, the selected element is omitted iff it has a preceding sibling element with the same contents.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ZD="http://xyz.abc">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/ZD:Report_Data/ZD:Report_Entry">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::ZD:Report_Entry[(ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode = current()/ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode) and (ZD:empStat.name = current()/ZD:empStat.name) and (ZD:worker/ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate = current()/ZD:worker/ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate) and (ZD:worker/ZD:empStat.actvInd = current()/ZD:worker/ZD:empStat.actvInd)]"/>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Checking for the preceding sibling element is done by selecting a preceding sibling `<ZD:Report_Entry>` element. A condition for that element is that its four content element values match those of the respective content element values of the selected node (`current()`).

If you need to compare the records for equality based on different criteria, modify the part in the square brackets.

***Test case***

This example document:

```
<ZD:Report_Data xmlns:ZD="http://xyz.abc">

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>1</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Terminated Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>0</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>1</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>1</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>1</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>1</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>1</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>1</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>1</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>1</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>1</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>1</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>1</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>1</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>1</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>1</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>1</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>1</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>1</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>2</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>1</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>1</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

<ZD:Report_Entry>
<ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
<ZD:empStat.name>Terminated Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
<ZD:worker>
<ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
<ZD:empStat.actvInd>0</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
</ZD:worker>
</ZD:Report_Entry>

</ZD:Report_Data>
```

gets transformed into this output:

```
<ZD:Report_Data xmlns:ZD="http://xyz.abc">
    <ZD:Report_Entry>
        <ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
        <ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
        <ZD:worker>
            <ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
            <ZD:empStat.actvInd>1</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
        </ZD:worker>
    </ZD:Report_Entry>
    <ZD:Report_Entry>
        <ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
        <ZD:empStat.name>Terminated Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
        <ZD:worker>
            <ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
            <ZD:empStat.actvInd>0</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
        </ZD:worker>
    </ZD:Report_Entry>
    <ZD:Report_Entry>
        <ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>A</ZD:empStat.emplStatusCode>
        <ZD:empStat.name>Active Employee</ZD:empStat.name>
        <ZD:worker>
            <ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>1/1/1968</ZD:empStat.lastUpdateDate>
            <ZD:empStat.actvInd>2</ZD:empStat.actvInd>
        </ZD:worker>
    </ZD:Report_Entry>
</ZD:Report_Data>
```

***Update:*** Correctly copied the `<ZD:Record_Entry>` element instead of just its contents.

Comment: Hi O.R. Mapper.  I am still getting the full file with all 20k+ records and not just the two that I need.  I updated my sample XML output and also my desired XML output in my original post.  I also am wondering if any of this has to do with the fact that two of the fields in each record are beneath the zd:worker node?

Comment: I tried testing it in XML Playground and the duplicates remained.

Comment: Hi.  I got it working using Sean B. Durkin's solution above.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @LC_123: I'm not sure what went wrong for you. When I change the namespace URI to yours in my XSLT and apply my XSLT to your Xml document, I'm getting no duplicates, just the records indicated in your example.

Comment: I know.  It was my mistake.  I didn't understand how namespaces work.  I am completely new to this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put something together that would achieve what you want whilst working generally, not specifically for this XML schema.

I'm tired and it's very fudgey and hackey (take note before hating, people), so there's probably better ways, but it seems to work.

```
    <!-- root and static content -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='*/*' />
        </root>
    </xsl:template>


    <!-- children - output only unique -->
    <xsl:template match='*'>
        <xsl:variable name='node' select='.' />

        <!-- does this node have identical siblings up ahead? If so, skip it, and we'll output a sibling later -->
        <xsl:variable name='has_identical_siblings'>
            <xsl:for-each select='following-sibling::*[name() = name($node)]'>
                <xsl:call-template name='check_identical'>
                    <xsl:with-param name='this_node_profile'>
                        <xsl:copy-of select='$node' />
                    </xsl:with-param>
                    <xsl:with-param name='check_against'>
                        <xsl:copy-of select='.' />
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- output? -->
        <xsl:if test='not(normalize-space($has_identical_siblings))'>
            <xsl:copy-of select='.' />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- util: two nodes are identical? -->
    <xsl:template name='check_identical'>
        <xsl:param name='this_node_profile' />
        <xsl:param name='check_against' />
        <xsl:if test='$this_node_profile = $check_against'>true</xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

[You can run it here](http://www.xmlplayground.com/pTadtm) (see output source - one active employee, one teminated).

Comment: This works!  Unfortunately it's timing out after 30 mins of trying to  process the full 20,000 records.  Thanks so much for the effort!

Comment: Almost certainly due to the `for-each`, which is always best avoided in XSLT but is occasionally (in fact almost exclusively for situations like this) unavoidable. You could up your server's max execution time. Feel free to give the answer a vote up if it helped you - I won't complain :)

Comment: thanks.  I got it running within the timeout parameters using sean b. durkin's solution above.  thanks so much for your help!